# Why won't my trivial LSTM overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I created a very trivial LSTM to try to predict a short sequence, but it won't overfit and approach a loss of zero the way I expect.

Instead it just converges around a loss of ~1.5, even if it definitely has enough degrees of freedom to learn this sequence verbatim.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

#
# Training data, just a single sequence
#
train_input = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0]]
train_output = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0]]

#
# Training metadata
#
batch_size = 1
sequence_length = 10
n_classes = 9

# Network size
rnn_cell_size = 10
rnn_layers = 2
embedding_rank = 3

#
# Training hyperparameters
#
epochs = 100
n_batches = 100
learning_rate = 0.01

#
# Model
#
features = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="features")
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_classes, embedding_rank], -1.0, 1.0))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, features)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_cell_size) for i in range(rnn_layers)])
initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
cell, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)
# Convert sequences x batches x outputs to (sequences * batches) x outputs
flat_lstm_output = tf.reshape(cell, [-1, rnn_cell_size])
output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=flat_lstm_output, num_outputs=n_classes)
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(output)

#
# Training
#
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length])
# Convert sequences x batches x targets to (sequences * batches) x targets
flat_targets = tf.reshape(targets, [-1])
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(flat_targets, softmax)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(epochs):
        loss_sum = 0
        epoch_start = time.time()
        for j in range(n_batches):
            _, step_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], {
                    features: train_input,
                    targets: train_output,
            })
            loss_sum = loss_sum + step_loss
        print('avg_loss', loss_sum / n_batches, 'avg_time', (time.time() - epoch_start) / n_batches)
```

I get the feeling something very basic is missing here - what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I tried to simplify it even more, and now I'm down to the following even more trivial example (that also doesn't converge):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

#
# Training data, just a single sequence
#
train_input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
train_output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

#
# Training metadata
#
batch_size = 1
sequence_length = 5
n_classes = 6

#
# Training hyperparameters
#
epochs = 100
n_batches = 100
learning_rate = 0.01

#
# Model
#
features = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
one_hot = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(features, n_classes)
output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=one_hot, num_outputs=10)
output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=output, num_outputs=n_classes)

#
# Training
#
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
one_hot_targets = tf.one_hot(targets, depth=n_classes)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(one_hot_targets, output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(epochs):
        loss_sum = 0
        epoch_start = time.time()
        for j in range(n_batches):
            _, step_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], {
                    features: train_input,
                    targets: train_output,
            })
            loss_sum = loss_sum + step_loss
        print('avg_loss', loss_sum / n_batches, 'avg_time', (time.time() - epoch_start) / n_batches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the lower values for the learning rate (e.g., 0.001 or 0.0001)?

Answer (score 0):

Your networks aren't fitting (let alone overfitting) because you don't have enough data. The LSTM has only one sequence and the MLP has 5 datapoints.

Compare this with the number of parameters you need to estimate: your MLP has 120 parameters (if I'm counting correctly). There is no way you can estimate all these with only 5 datapoints unless you're very lucky. (you can make it more likely to converge by splitting your sequence into smaller batches, but even then it won't converge very often).

In short, neural networks need a decent amount of data to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was three-fold.

1) The example without the RNN converges if I replace the default activation in the fully connected layers (relu) with tanh.

This seems to be because the relu ignores a lot of input (everything below zero) and doesn't provide a gradient at all. With more input it might have worked.

2) The example WITH the RNN needs to remove the activation in the final fully connected layer (before the softmax) completely using None - it doesn't converge well (or at all, in most combinations) with an activation of the fully connected layer in front of the softmax.

3) The RNN example also needs to remove the explicit softmax, since sparse_softmax_cross_entropy applies softmax already.

Finally working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

#
# Training data, just a single sequence
#
train_input = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0]]
train_output = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0]]

#
# Training metadata
#
batch_size = 1
sequence_length = 10
n_classes = 9

# Network size
rnn_cell_size = 10
rnn_layers = 2
embedding_rank = 3

#
# Training hyperparameters
#
epochs = 100
n_batches = 100
learning_rate = 0.01

#
# Model
#
features = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="features")
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_classes, embedding_rank], -1.0, 1.0))
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, features)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_cell_size) for i in range(rnn_layers)])
initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
cell, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embed, initial_state=initial_state)
# Convert [batche_size, sequence_length, rnn_cell_size] to [(batch_size * sequence_length), rnn_cell_size]
flat_lstm_output = tf.reshape(cell, [-1, rnn_cell_size])
output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=flat_lstm_output, num_outputs=n_classes, activation_fn=None)

#
# Training
#
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length])
# Convert [batch_size, sequence_length] to [batch_size * sequence_length]
flat_targets = tf.reshape(targets, [-1])
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(flat_targets, output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(epochs):
        loss_sum = 0
        epoch_start = time.time()
        for j in range(n_batches):
            _, step_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], {
                    features: train_input,
                    targets: train_output,
            })
            loss_sum = loss_sum + step_loss
        print('avg_loss', loss_sum / n_batches, 'avg_time', (time.time() - epoch_start) / n_batches)
```